# Get List of Push Pin Details from Polygon

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

How do I select the list of push pins inside the polygon in bong maps.

In the example below I see the push pins inside the selected polygon get highlighted but is there a code sample that i can see/use where they maybe get a list of push pins details on selection ?

http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Select%20Data%20in%20Drawn%20Polygon%20Area

Answer (score 0):

From the source code, it seems to be generated randomly. To get the list
use the variable pinLayer.

var pushpins = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getPushpins(30, map.getBounds(), { color: 'purple' });
pinLayer.add(pushpins);